# g++ error using -flto option

Tags: c++, boost, linker, g++

I am trying to enable link time optimization in g++. My program compiles fine without the `-flto` option. When I add it to my Makefile the object files compile without errors, e.g.

```
g++ main.cpp -I ../includes -std=c++0x -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-vla -flto -D INFO_ -c -o .obj/main.o
```

But when it comes to link the program:

```
g++ -fwhole-program -I ../includes -std=c++0x -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-vla -flto -D INFO_ .obj/main.o .obj/atom.o .obj/bee.o .obj/colony.o ../includes/.obj/error.o ../includes/.obj/CmdLine.o ../includes/boost_lib_deb/libboost_program_options.a ../includes/gmp_lib_deb/lib/libgmpxx.a ../includes/gmp_lib_deb/lib/libgmp.a -o BeeBench
```

I get a lot of errors like these:

```
includes/gmp_lib_deb/lib/libgmpxx.a ../includes/gmp_lib_deb/lib/libgmp.a -o BeeBench
`typeinfo for boost::program_options::too_many_positional_options_error' referenced in section `.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options33too_many_positional_options_errorE[vtable for boost::program_options::too_many_positional_options_error]' of ../includes/boost_lib_deb/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): defined in discarded section `.gnu.linkonce.t._ZTIN5boost15program_options33too_many_positional_options_errorE' of .obj/main.o (symbol from plugin)

`typeinfo for boost::program_options::too_many_positional_options_error' referenced in section `.rodata._ZTIN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options33too_many_positional_options_errorEEE[typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::too_many_positional_options_error>]' of ../includes/boost_lib_deb/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): defined in discarded section `.gnu.linkonce.t._ZTIN5boost15program_options33too_many_positional_options_errorE' of .obj/main.o (symbol from plugin)
`typeinfo for boost::program_options::invalid_command_line_style' referenced in section `.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options26invalid_command_line_styleE[vtable for boost::program_options::invalid_command_line_style]' of ../includes/boost_lib_deb/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): defined in discarded section `.gnu.linkonce.t._ZTIN5boost15program_options26invalid_command_line_styleE' of .obj/main.o (symbol from plugin)
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. I compile all my object files using `-flto`. The libs, namely Boost and GMP, are compiled without `-flto` option. Is this causing the error? The gcc manual says that its ok to mix object files compiled with & without `-flto` option. Or am I missing something else, for example what is this plugin the error is speaking about?

I am using G++ 4.6.3 on Debian Wheezy.

**UPDATE:**

As adviced in the comments I made a minimal example. The code of my test program is only this:

```
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"

int main ( int argC, char* argV[] )
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using:

```
g++ -o test -I ../includes -Wall -std=c++0x test.cpp -flto -fwhole-program -static
```

it gives similar errors as described above. If I omit the -static, -flto OR std=c++0x option it compiles without errors. The -fwhole-program option does not change the result. I now also tested with G++ 4.7, same error.

Any suggestions? Is this really a compiler error, or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Can be compiler bug. Have you tried to create a minimal testcase which uses Boost.ProgramOptions?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce these errors on any of the machines I currently have - one of them raises different linker errors, because it doesn't have statically linkable libraries, and the second one is Mac where GCC doesn't like static linkage at all. I'll try it when, I'll be at my own Linux machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since I found no evidence, that there is something wrong with my code, I have posted a [Boost bugreport](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6903). It was reproduced by other boost users as well, therefore I think it is actually a bug within boost or the g++. By now there was no response from the Boost maintainer. I'll update this post when there is one.

**Update**

It seems like the g++ linker-plugin is causing the problem (Still I have no idea why). Therefore a possible work around is to disable the linker-plugin by using `-fno-use-linker-plugin`.

Comment: Doesn't -fno-use-linker-plugin negate the -flto option and therefore has the same effect as not using -flto?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: No. See -flto in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html. However it states that if the linker-plugin is deaktivated -fwhole-program should be used.

Comment: @Haatschii ... but it also says that `whole-program` should *not* be used with `lto`.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Interesting, this actually changed since I asked this question. In https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html it explicitly says in the LTO section to enable `-whole-program` if no linker plugin is available.

Comment: @Haatschii Interesting. I thought that might be the case, but you only wrote that comment a few months ago.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Yea sorry, my fault. I didn't actually check the site I was linking. I just assumed that it was still in the same state as when I last read the section on LTO.

Answer (score 3):

Something within the library references the typeinfo of the that particular class (typically things like a "catch" statement for that particular exception or a "dynamic_cast").  Hence the "referenced in section" in your error message.

However, for the typeinfo to be generated, a non-inline non-pure virtual function has to be present in one of the compilation units.  If the function is defined within the class definition, this does not count (it is inlined and treated as inlined for linkage, even if you pass "-fno-default-inline").

So, the dynamic_cast or catch statement is probably not working as the author intended; the issue just was never noticed until LTO was attempted on the header.

So, I'd call it a BOOST error and/or a shortcoming of g++.

Answer (score 1):

`-flto` flag must be present in both compile and linker command lines in order to work. `-fwhole-program`, on the other hand, is not needed at all. LTO will not work with translation units that were not compiled with LTO support, by the way.

Comment: As I wrote in the question -flto is present in both g++ calls. The same error occurs when compiling without -fwhole-program, which by the way is usefull as far I know, since I am not using the Linker Plugin (which btw still produces the same error).

Answer (score 0):

12 years later. "-flto" must be present as both compiler and linker flag.
you also need "-ffat-lto-objects" compiler flag.