# Linker error with Boost, referenced in discarded section

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 which have GCC 4.6, but I need C++11 for my project so I used https://askubuntu.com/a/271561 to install 4.8 and everything seem to work, I can compile my code.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
```

I also downloaded boost 1.55 from the web page and built it using.

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

And everything works, it seems to build for gcc 4.8. But when I try to link my project I get linker errors to boost:

```
Linking CXX executable server
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian16bad_day_of_monthEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian16bad_day_of_monthEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian16bad_day_of_monthEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian16bad_day_of_monthEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian16bad_day_of_monthEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_12bad_weak_ptrEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_12bad_weak_ptrEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_12bad_weak_ptrEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_12bad_weak_ptrEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_12bad_weak_ptrEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian9bad_monthEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian9bad_monthEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian9bad_monthEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian9bad_monthEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian9bad_monthEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I first built boost with the old version, but after seeing that this could relate to different compiler versions being used I removed the boost folder, extracted the source again and built everything from scratch, rebuilt my code too but I still get the same error.

UPDATE:
Here's what I get from 'VERBOSE=1 make', I'm using CMake to build the project.

```
Linking CXX executable server
cd <path>/build/server && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/server.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -g -O0 -Wall -fno-inline -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -D__GLIBCXX_DEBUG     --coverage -lrt -fno-use-linker-plugin CMakeFiles/server.dir/main.cpp.o  -o server -rdynamic ../core/libcore.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_date_time-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a -lpthread ../messages/libmessages.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_date_time-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a -lprotobuf
```

UPDATE:

After removing boost 1.46 from apt-get I get this error instead

```
Linking CXX executable server
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_for(timespec const&)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x1290): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
```

Which it seems should be solved by the -lrt flag which is already included in the linker flags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811503/unusual-c-linker-error-defined-in-discarded-section . Make sure that you don't use libraries compiled with different versions of GCC. I mean C++ libraries compiled by an older GCC, because C libraries usually don't suffer from binary incompabilities. Also if you provide the complete link line it could be handy to track down the problem

Comment: I can't use the repos since the boost version for 12.04 is too old.

Comment: Also the problem may be caused by a bug in `GCC` (congratulations!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050140/g-error-using-flto-option

Comment: Added linker command, I thought rebuilding boost with the new g++ would help. Adding -fno-linker-plugin to the linker flags didn't help :/

Comment: Also I've encountered a message telling that [a while ago] such problems were caused by incompatibilities between GCC and binutils. 2.24.0 is known to work correctly w/ gcc-4.8.2 :)

Comment: Oh come on.... :) I'll look into getting 4.8.2 then.

Comment: Also, a question: do you have boost libraries of a previous version or versions? Are you sure that the linker doesn't mix them? Boost is known to be too complex and thus fragile and sensitive to compiler etc.

Comment: And yes, I've checked. When I installed gcc-4.8 in my system (from distro packages), `binutils` were updated by dependencies too. So perhaps older binutils could be the cause.

Comment: Ah yes, I had boost 1.46 installed from apt. After removing them I get a new error, updated the question. I tried "apt-get upgrade binutils" but there's no new version available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-lrt` to the end of the link line to resolve the problem w/ `clock_gettime()`

Comment: Heh-heh. To the _end_ of the link line :)

Comment: It builds! it builds!

Comment: The problem you've encountered is caused by the fact that GNU linker (and probably other, dunno) [by default] doesn't remember what functions it encounters in libraries being linked in if these functions aren't referenced somewhere in previously seen code. So there could be situations when you have to specify a certain library multiple times, in the middle of the link line for the first time, and near its end, because of circular references between libraries being linked in.